# Import XML into a Grails Domain Class

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

I am reading an XML file with a schema based on a Domain Class.

Here is a simple example for illustration (my current situation concerns a lot of fields from a lot of classes) :

```
class Player {
  String name
  Date birthDate
}
```

The XML file to read is :

```
<players>
<player name='P1' birthDate='12-09-1983'/>
</players>
```

So my question is:
When parsing the XML file, I create Player instances with the following Groovy code:

```
def players = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlFile)
players.player.each() {p ->
  new Player(name: p.@name, birthDate: p.@birthDate).save()
}
```

Is there another simpler way to do it ? 
Like params binding when creating/updating a domain object using code like `new Player(params)` or `player.properties = params` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, you can give directly the list of attributes to your domain class constructor with **attributes()**.

```
def players = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlFile)
players.player.each() {p ->
    new Player(p.attributes()).save()
}
```

Comment: Thx! This was exacly what I needed