# Converting xml to domain object in Grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-domain-class, xmlslurper

I'm a grails newbie working on a project for fun.  I'm serializing a class like this:

```
def msg = (listing as XML).toString()
```

the trying to deserialize a class using the XMLSlurper like this:

```
def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(listingString)
def sellerNode = root.seller
```

I'm trying to reconstruct this object:

```
Listing{

    Date dateCreated
        String description
        Date endDateTime
        String name
        Float startingPrice
        Customer winner
        static hasMany = [bids: Bid] // B-4
        static belongsTo = [seller: Customer]
    }

}
```

from this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing>
    <bids>
        <bid>
            <amount>10.5</amount>
            <bidder>
                <accountExpired>false</accountExpired>
                <accountLocked>false</accountLocked>
                <dateCreated/>
                <emailAddress>validguy@valid.com</emailAddress>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <password>secret</password>
                <passwordExpired>false</passwordExpired>
                <username>validguy</username>
            </bidder>
            <dateCreated>2012-04-08 21:16:41.423 CDT</dateCreated>
            <listing/>
        </bid>
        <bid>
            <amount>10.0</amount>
            <bidder>
                <accountExpired>false</accountExpired>
                <accountLocked>false</accountLocked>
                <dateCreated/>
                <emailAddress>validguy@valid.com</emailAddress>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <password>secret</password>
                <passwordExpired>false</passwordExpired>
                <username>validguy</username>
            </bidder>
            <dateCreated>2012-04-08 21:16:41.415 CDT</dateCreated>
            <listing/>
        </bid>
    </bids>
    <dateCreated/>
    <description>A test listing</description>
    <endDateTime>2012-04-09 21:16:41.407 CDT</endDateTime>
    <name>Default</name>
    <seller>
        <accountExpired>false</accountExpired>
        <accountLocked>false</accountLocked>
        <dateCreated/>
        <emailAddress>validguy@valid.com</emailAddress>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <password>secret</password>
        <passwordExpired>false</passwordExpired>
        <username>validguy</username>
    </seller>
    <startingPrice>10.0</startingPrice>
    <wasNotificationSent>false</wasNotificationSent>
    <winner>
        <accountExpired>false</accountExpired>
        <accountLocked>false</accountLocked>
        <dateCreated/>
        <emailAddress>validguy@valid.com</emailAddress>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
        <password>secret</password>
        <passwordExpired>false</passwordExpired>
        <username>validguy</username>
    </winner>
</listing>
```

First I'm having issues getting to the values of each node.  I've tried def seller = new Customer(name:sellerNode.@username) but that doesn't work since I assume @username needs to be an attribute and not an element.
Second, do I have to parse this xml "by hand"? Isn't there a better way to deserialize this xml automatically?

I already looked at a couple of posts and including this one: [Import XML into a Grails Domain Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519395/import-xml-into-a-grails-domain-class)  however as you can see, my xml doesn't have attributes like the xml in this post.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the source of the XML is a web request, you can add `parseRequest: true` to the UrlMapping for your controller, grails will parse the XML request automatically.  The XML will be presented as `params` and you can do data binding the same as any other request.

If you're getting the XML from another source, take a look at the XML to parameter map conversion in the class [`XMLParsingParameterCreationListener.groovy`](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-converters/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/converters/XMLParsingParameterCreationListener.groovy).

Comment: @atylor:  Thanks for the reply.  I haven't had a chance to try this yet.  I'll do so tonight and get to you tomorrow.

Comment: More details at http://grails.org/doc/2.2.4/guide/webServices.html - search for "parseRequest" and you'll find something like this: `"/product/$id"(controller: "product", parseRequest: true)`

Answer (score 0):

I did look at the class aTaylor suggested but due to time constraints I ended up parsing the xml with the slurper this way:

```
def listing = new XmlSlurper().parseText(listingXML)
def winner = listing."winner"."username".text()
```

I was constrained by the fact that I can only get at text values.  For instance, I couldn't deserialize the bids elements into a collection and perform calculations like bids.Max(b->b.amount).  That was my ultimate goal.

BTW - This is was not a web request.  It was a MQ message serialized as xml.