# Reading from XML and storing the values in database using grails

Tags: grails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import XML into a Grails Domain Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519395/import-xml-into-a-grails-domain-class)

say am having the xml file like below, 
Now i want to insert these firstname, deptname and empid into the database using grails
can anyone suggest an idea in this.

`<employees>`
 `<employee>`
      `<firstname>Marios</firstname>`
      `<deptname>ITdepartment</deptname>`
      `<empid>123</empid>`
  `</employee>`
  `<employee>`
      `<firstname>Ben</firstname>`
      `<deptname>Management</deptname>`
      `<empid>124</empid>`
  `</employee>`
`</employees>`

Comment: There are plenty of articles out there, you should be able to get ideas just by searching the web.  I would recommend you start off with [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  After that, you can create a [domain class in GORM](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.htm) for employee.  Then use [XML Slurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy's+XmlSlurper) to parse the XML and populate your domain object before you save it to the database.

Comment: This should point you in the right direction: [xml][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519395/import-xml-into-a-grails-domain-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all, I got the answer how to do that am posting here for others for their knowledge if changes required any can suggest me

`def Employee = new XmlParser().parse("Your Xml file path")`
   `def set1 = sql.dataSet("Your field name in Xml")`
   `Employee.employee.each {`
   `def firstname = it.firstname.text()`
   `def deptname = it.deptname.text()`
   `def empid = it.empid.text()`
   `set1.add(first_name:firstname,dept_name:deptname,emp_id:empid)`
}